# wcf Service Known type attribute question

Tags: wcf

i wanna add a service behavior(or anything u'll suggest) that will automatically insert the types from dll to the service known types of the service

is it possible? how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Known type attributes are passed to the DataContractSerializer constructor. You can [customize the way this serializer is instantiated](http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx) and provide the known types to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx) of the serializer by reflecting over your assemblies and finding all types that derive from a base class.

Here's a sample code (not tested):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface FooContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [KnownTypesDataContractFormat(typeof(SomeBaseType))]
    void MyOperation(SomeBaseType arg);
}

public class KnownTypesDataContractFormatAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public Type BaseType { get; private set; }
    public KnownTypesDataContractFormatAttribute(Type baseType)
    {
        BaseType = baseType;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation proxy)
    {
        IOperationBehavior innerBehavior = new KnownTypesDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(description, BaseType);
        innerBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(description, proxy);
    }


    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        IOperationBehavior innerBehavior = new KnownTypesDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(description, BaseType);
        innerBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(description, dispatch);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription description)
    { }
}

public class KnownTypesDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    public Type BaseType { get; private set; }
    public KnownTypesDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, Type baseType) : base(operationDescription) 
    {
        BaseType = baseType;
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes()
    {
        // Try to find all types that derive from BaseType in the 
        // executing assembly and add them to the knownTypes collection
        return 
            from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where type != BaseType && BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(type)
            select type;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry i'm pretty wick in wcf, how do i make this on entire service an not per method?

Comment: By implementing IServiceBehavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) instead of IOperationBehavior